# Will plugging in two connectors to my monitor fry it?

Tags: display

I have a monitor with one HDMI and one VGA connector.

If I were to plug in one computer with the HDMI and a different one with the VGA, what would happen? Would it fry the monitor?

Comment: If you did what you describe, you would have a single monitor connected to two different PCs, and would have to use input (or similar button) to change which PC would be displayed

Answer (score 3):

**No**, it won't fry your Monitor.

If you look closely, you should have an `Input` button on your monitor.
If you plug in two inputs, you will have the function to switch between these two.

I am currently working on two monitors, and both of them are connected to two different inputs. So it's like I have 4 screens.